# How to refactoring a cloned rails repo?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, refactoring, clone, repository

Being new to Rails, git and terminal.  What is the best method of renaming a local version of a cloned repo from github.

e.g.

**[angular+rails+yeoman](https://github.com/vlad/yeoman-rails-angular)** I think will be a great bootstrap for a project.  The problem being after clone, I would want to give my app its own name.  What is the best method in accomplishing this?

yeoman-rails-angular becomes clients-app

I found this resource?  But it just doesnt seems very "rails-y"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding, but if you are cloning the repository, you can rename it as you do so with:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/vlad/yeoman-rails-angular.git clients-app
```

Comment: no you certainly were not... I'm super new to rails, and git.

Comment: No worries.  Glad to be of some help.